# Regex not match all elements

Tags: regex

I have wrote some regex to match the first number in a number of project

```
^[^£]*£(?:[0-9\.,]+)[^£]*£([0-9\.,]+)
```

The problem which I am having is that it is not match all occurrences for the first number when they are being parsed below

```
RRP �50.00 - Now �39.99    // Not working

RRP �45 - Now �38          //Working
```

I was just wondering what is wrong because I cannot work it out. Thanks for any advice which you can give

Comment: What language are you using to evaluate that regex? When your regex it appears to be working. (I replaced the entities that my browser didn't recognize in your example with £.)

Comment: Same here.  I would guess the problem is related to character encodings, but if that were the case, nothing would match.

Comment: I am using C# to parse the RRP prices. From a web site

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly specifying a character that might have issue(s) in regex engine to evaluate you may also try using it equivalent code:

```
^[^\u00A3]*\u00A3(?:[0-9\.,]+)[^\u00A3]*\u00A3([0-9\.,]+)
```

Not sure it solves your problem, but give it a try.

Comment: No, that's not it. Inside a character class (i.e. the square brackets), `,(\.\d+)?` is just a bunch of literal characters (other than `\d`, which still matches any digit).   Read this for a more complete explanation: [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: @AlanMoore, Yes, i have removed the character classes for the same reason.

Comment: That's better, but I don't think it solves the problem.  In fact, I'm not sure what the problem *is*.  If `\d+((,\d+)?\.\d+)?` matches the numbers correctly, `[0-9\.,]+` should match them too, decimals or no.  And so it does, in my tests.